# what's the difference between 試験する and 受験する?

Tags: word-choice

The title is explicit, what's the difference between **試験する** and **受験する** ? According to my dictionnary they both mean "to pass an exam", but I guess there is a nuance.

Comment: Which dictionary are you using? Neither one means "to pass an exam."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

試験する: to make experiments on something or someone.
受験する: take an examination

試験する
experiment ((on animals/with medicine)); test ((a thing)); put ((a thing)) to the test
[https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/試験する/#je-30916](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E8%A9%A6%E9%A8%93%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B/#je-30916)

受験する
受験の準備をする
prepare for an examination

私立校を受験する
take [((英))sit (for)] an entrance examination to [for] a private school
[https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/受験/#je-34394](https://dictionary.goo.ne.jp/word/en/%E5%8F%97%E9%A8%93/#je-34394)